# macOS and Swift. Changing EXIF data causes URLs to be imported differently

Tags: swift, macos, url, exif

I am writing an app that receives URLs sent by "Open with…"

The app uses ExifTool to modify the EXIF data in image files.

I select several image files in Finder and select "Open with…", choose my app and the URLs are received like this :

```
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate
{
  lazy var lastImportTime: Date = .init()

  func application(_ application: NSApplication, open urls: [URL])
  {
    let currentImportTime = Date()

    let timeInterval = currentImportTime.timeIntervalSince(lastImportTime)

    if timeInterval > 1
    {
      DataProvider.clear()

      lastImportTime = Date()
    }

    print(urls.count)

    for url in urls
    {
      DataProvider.addURL(url)
    }

    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .onDataLoaded, object: nil)
  }
```

I had to add the import time stuff to cope with this method being called more than once for each "import".

If I send image files that have not had their camera EXIF data touched, all files are received in one call to this method. However, as soon as the EXIF data is changed, the URLs are then sent in two calls, one for the modified files, the second for the "virgin" files.

Any insights on why this might be happening?

Comment: "If I send image files" what does this mean, does the app send files to itself?

Comment: Like I said, sending image files means selecting them in Finder, then clicking on "Open with…"

Comment: Ok, I thought it was your app that changed Exif data and then sent them.

Comment: Well, yes and no. My app does change Exif data, but then, if I send the changed files back to my app from Finder, that's when I encountered the problem. In fact, I found the answer; it was a subtly different parameter I was sending to the files from my app when writing the Exif. Now I am using the correct parameter, the problem is solved.